# SherlockActionBar styling did not apply on ICS

Tags: android, styles, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-theme

I'm facing with a weird problem with SherlockActionBar.

I need to customize theme `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`.

If I set theme `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar` in AndroidManifest, everything works fine (Gingerbread and ICS too).

But if i make my own theme, which is inherited from `Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar`, it will not apply on devices with ICS+. Even if the custom style is empty as follows:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <style name="customTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar" >
  </style>
</resources>
```

and in manifest in application node:

```
    android:theme="@style/customTheme"
```

This is ok on Gingerbread, but on ICS+ there is Theme.Sherlock.Light applied. Any solution?

Comment: Do you have a values-v11 folder by any chance?

Comment: Yes, that was a problem, I forgot that I have v-11 folder with the same name of that Theme. Thank you Ahmad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I already mentioned in the comments, you'll have to check if you have a values-v11 folder with a theme that is overriding your theme in Android API 11+.